# Can't Delete Node of Firebase Database

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database

I call the function to delete as follows:

```
<div *ngFor="let out of cart_checkouts">
<button type="button" (click)="RemoveCheckoutRecord(out.checkoutID)">Delete</button>
</div>
```

This executes the following function:

```
RemoveCheckoutRecord(rowID) {
this.firestore.doc('cart_checkouts/' + rowID).delete();
}
```

I've also tried:

```
RemoveCheckoutRecord(rowID) {
var db = firebase.database();
var ref = db.ref("cart_checkouts");
ref.child(rowID).remove();
}
```

Neither one of the functions throw an error; they simply don't work. The preceding two functions seem to just be for collections and this is a node on a realtime database not a collection.

The following works to delete the node -MRGk9sayjVDB8F15TM3 but I need it to delete by checkoutID because I can't reference the nodes by their keys.

```
var db = firebase.database();
var ref = db.ref("cart_checkouts/-MRGk9sayjVDB8F15TM3");
ref.remove();
```

The database structure looks like this:

```
cart_checkouts 
   - MRGk9sSNzdImNPmfFJo 
      -- checkoutID: 1 
      -- checkoutProductName: "Adult Female Bike" 
   - MRLp4ettEMfSZjnBSGF 
      -- checkoutID: 3 
      -- checkoutProductName: "Adult Unisex Helmet"
```

Answer (score 0):

You say the remove is working on the db ref; try the code below to get this ref based on the rowID

```
RemoveCheckoutRecord(rowID) {
    var db = firebase.database();
    var ref = db.ref("cart_checkouts/" + rowID).remove();
}
```

Comment: Then I assume rowID does not match checkoutID? You should investigate why that is the case

Comment: Thanks, RobrechtVM. rowID does match checkoutID. I console logged it and saw that it did. The problem is that an automatic ID is assigned to the database so the structure looks like this:

cart_checkouts
- MRGk9sSNzdImNPmfFJo
-- checkoutID: 1
-- checkoutProductName: "Adult Female Bike"
- MRLp4ettEMfSZjnBSGF
-- checkoutID: 3
-- checkoutProductName:  "Adult Unisex Helmet"

Comment: Edited question/post to show the database structure.